# Pass a Nodejs object to my javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs object like so:

```
var OBJ = require(__dirname + '/public/convertcsv.json');
```

and I use this javascript that I link to my html webpage like so(within Nodeserver.js):

```
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/js/Script.js', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
    });
```

How do I access '
**OBJ**
' in my Script.js

Assume my Nodeserver.js is a standard server that can handle requests and responses.

I am trying to do this without NodeJS Express. So please don't post Express answers.

Comment: **OBJ** variable is in `Script.js`?

Comment: @MichalHainc I'm not at all skilled with ajax. Could you please show me an example ??

Comment: I really require an example using basic js. I've not grown to understand jquery yet. I am a logical kind of programmer at heart and jquery is just too much semantics.

Comment: Is it possible using an automated GET/POST request right when the page is loading? I need to access a variable in the server from a client side javascript. It shouldn't be this complex should it?